# how to change shape of CircleAvatar widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: cell item]

I want to change the shape of first circle avatar. Is it possible using `.of(context).copyWith`?. Because `CircleAvatar` has used `AnimatedContainer` for shape.

Comment: You can always wrap it with `ClipOval`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the shape of a `CircleAvatar` to be anything other than a circle.
It is not possible to modify a Widget after it was instantiated.

Instead, create your own Widget using composition. Let you guide by the [`CircleAvatar` implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/db747aa133/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/circle_avatar.dart#L219).

```dart
Container(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: image,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),

    // your own shape
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below:

```
Container(
  width: 45.0,
  height: 45.0,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 20, 45),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
       Radius.circular(18),
    ),
),
child: const Center(
  child: FaIcon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.bitcoin,
    color: Colors.amber,
  ),
),
),
```